Task execution in qterminal dopdown
I was new to how the dropdown works. It lost focus and disappeared. Do tasks still get executed or are they aborted?

To learn more about Drop Down menu, I suggest consulting the Lubuntu manual
https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.2/qterminal.html
You didn't provide release, so I've provided the link for the 24.04 manual; adjust URL to match if using a different release
You'll note in the manual reference to a key

To use the drop down function of QTerminal once launched press F12 to
have the terminal drop down or roll up.

For more about drop down you may get more from @vanadium's answer, I haven't found it very helpful for how I use machines, so I've not explored it much.. but my testing agrees with what was already provided (ie. continue to run until you close the dropdown terminal)

A dropdown terminal in so called "quake mode" continues running in the background. When summoned, it reappears on the top of the screen as you left it.
So yes, likely your process is still running. Consult the documentation on how to make the terminal appear again - typically this is using a shortcut key: once the terminal is visible again, you will see any output of the process you have been running.
